# Bash parameters not detected

Tags: bash, shell, sh

When I attempt to execute my bash script like this:

`bin/provision-pulsar-commands -t development -n provisioning`

the outputs print:

> TENANT =
>
> NAMESPACE =

Here is my script (provision-pulsar-commands):

```
#!/bin/bash


function display_usage {
    echo "You may override the namespace and tenant for all components for testing, if desired."
    echo "usage: bin/provision-pulsar-commands [-t tenant] [-n namespace]"
    echo "  -t      Override tenant (e.g. development) for all components"
    echo "  -n      Override namespace (e.g. provisioning) for all components"
    echo "  -h      display help"
    exit 1
    }

# check whether user had supplied -h or --help . If yes display usage
    if [[ ( $# == "--help") ||  $# == "-h" ]]
    then
        display_usage
        exit 0
    fi

while getopts tn option
do
case "${option}"
in
t) TENANT=${OPTARG};;
n) NAMESPACE=${OPTARG};;
esac
done

echo "TENANT = $TENANT"
echo "NAMESPACE = $NAMESPACE"
```

Why are my parameter values not getting picked up?
I'm basing my code on these examples:

- https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571
- https://www.poftut.com/how-to-pass-and-parse-linux-bash-script-arguments-and-parameters/

Clarification: My parameter values are optional. Also, when I pass -h or --help, my display_usage function is not called. It's not clear to me if that's related to the problem or not.

Comment: The test `[[ ( $# == "--help") ||  $# == "-h" ]]` will not work -- `$#` is the number of arguments (e.g. "2"), not the content of any of the arguments. You probably want `$1` instead. Also, the parentheses are not needed here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell `getopts` that `-t` and `-n` take arguments.

```
while getopts t:n: option; do
```

Without the colons, `-t` is recognized as an option, but `OPTARG` isn't set. The next argument (`development`) is neither `-t` nor `-n`, so terminates the loop.

Comment: Does that approach work for optional parameter values? (I clarified my question.)

Comment: `getopts` does not support options that take optional values. For example, `-t` either allows no argument, or it requires a single argument.

Comment: `$#` is the *number* of arguments; it is not a particular argument in `$@`. You need to add `h` to your optstring and treat it like any other option.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Based on your comment about `getopts`, it appears that the article I was following (https://www.lifewire.com/pass-arguments-to-bash-script-2200571) was incorrect about how to handle optional parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Add `:` to options that take arguments.

```
getopts t:n: option
```